# If statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

In my If-statement I have 6 conditions to test. Is there any way to mininmize this code below?

```
If (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "strControlId")).ToString.Contains("_default") AndAlso (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("numFormNumber")) = 1) AndAlso Not (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "strControlId")).ToString.Contains("RequiredOwner_default") AndAlso Not (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "strControlId")).ToString.Contains("cmbConsequence_default") AndAlso Not (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "strControlId")).ToString.Contains("cmbLikelihood_default") AndAlso Not (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "strControlId")).ToString.Contains("cmbSeverity_default") Then 

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about the logic of you "if" condition, but you can make the code more clean if you will use variables for repeated code.

```
 Dim strControlId As String = DataBinder.Eval(item, "strControlId")).ToString

If (strControlId.Contains("_default")_
 AndAlso (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("numFormNumber")) = 1) _
AndAlso Not (strControlId.Contains("RequiredOwner_default")_
 AndAlso Not (strControlId.Contains("cmbConsequence_default") _
AndAlso Not (strControlId.Contains("cmbLikelihood_default")_
 AndAlso Not (strControlId.Contains("cmbSeverity_default") Then
```

Comment: Not also the code is `more clean`. It also runs **faster**, because you evaluate the value of `DataBinder.Eval(item, "strControlId")).ToString` **only once**, instead of **6 times**.